# Version 1.5.0 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.6 or greater is required

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse

i downloaded latest ADT(adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522) for android programming for linux(64bit) and when i click to launch eclipse, it give me this error:

```
Version 1.5.0 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.6 or greater is required.
```

my linux is Mint 15 and all of my packages is update.

how i can fix this?

Comment: so what does `java -version` say?

Comment: java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.7.3

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just download last JDK from Oracle site [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: The latest version is Java 7.  Android is based on Java 6 which makes it a better choice.